# I get errors when I click the turtle game exit (X) button

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

Gets error when I click the exit (X) button:

> Failed to execute script pong

How can I close the turtle game by clicking the exit button with no error?

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. What is turtle game? What is the context here? Selenium?

Comment: Can you show us some code so we can confirm the cause of the error please?

Answer (score 0):

Getting errors from turtle when you close the window is highly indicative of not playing by the rules event-wise.  Typically it's due to a `while True:` loop instead of using timer events.  A properly event-drive turtle program should reach the `mainloop` statement (or one of its equivalents) and allow events to run the show.  If you want specifics, provide your code as part of your question.

Answer (score 0):

The error in the terminal must be due to the the `while True:` loop that most beginners like me use. Closing the window abruptly stops the process while the `while True:` loop was still going on. So, in order to avoid this error you can define a function

```
#Function
def quit():
    global running
    running = False

#Keybinding 
screen.onkeypress(quit, "q")

#Main game loop
while running:
   ...
   #update events

   ...
```